# CODE SHOWING ERROR MSSAGE :- error: incompatible types: Schedule_fragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Code showing uplisted error while adding clock to the fragmented activity.
 Error Message displayed is - error: incompatible types: Schedule_fragment cannot be converted to Fragment.
 I am new to this and have written this code from a youtube tutorial, now trying to merge with my code. Please help.

```
package com.example.fastfill.ui.main;   
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;  
import com.example.fastfill.R;


public class Schedule_fragment extends Fragment implements TimePickerFragment.TimePickerListener {
    private TextView displaytime;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.schedule_fragment);
        displaytime=findViewById(R.id.displaytime);
        Button showtime=findViewById(R.id.showtime);
        showtime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                DialogFragment timePickerFragment=new TimePickerFragment();
                timePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"timePicker");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
        displaytime.setText("Hour = " +hour + "Minute = "+ minute);
    }
}
```

Comment: Schedule_fragment  is an activity as it extends Activity,
You need to convert it to Fragment first.

Comment: You have a class Schedule_fragment which extends AppCompatActivity.
Even if you call it Schedule_fragment it is still an Activity because it extends Activity.
And an Activity is not an instance of a Fragment.
I suggest that you investiate the keyword 'extends' and 'implements' in Java to learn by yourself how to fix this Issue.

Comment: @Traendy I have edited the code by entending Fragment but now the features like setContentView, findViewById and getSupportFragmentManager() are underlined red as errors giving error " cannot resolve respective element "

Comment: As I said you should investigate the topic e.G here: https://www.javatpoint.com/inheritance-in-java
It is not feasible to explain Fragments and Activities and object oriented programming in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are extending AppCompatActivity, if you want to use Schedule_fragment as a fragment, you need to extend Fragment.

Comment: I have edited the code by entending Fragment but now the features like setContentView, findViewById and getSupportFragmentManager() are underlined red as errors giving error " cannot resolve respective element "